# NullReferenceException with System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser WPF

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, mshtml, dom

I have a C# WPF application with a web browser control (System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser) called wB. It is supposed to display a local html file, and some information parsed from it.

I get the a NullReferenceException as it says body is null in the last line (IHTMLElementCollection data = hDoc.body.children as IHTMLElementCollection)  with the following code:

```
wB.Navigate(new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute));                
HTMLDocument hDoc = (HTMLDocumentClass)wB.Document;
IHTMLElementCollection data = hDoc.body.children as IHTMLElementCollection;
```

If I do

```
wB.Navigate(new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute));                
HTMLDocument hDoc = (HTMLDocumentClass)wB.Document;
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Loc:" + hDoc.url);
IHTMLElementCollection data = hDoc.body.children as IHTMLElementCollection;
```

Everything works fine. Why is body showing up null in the 1st example, but fine for the second?

**Edit1**
The method is marked as [STAThread]...so I thought concurrency wouldn't be an issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
```

So you can be sure the document loaded already:

```
private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
  HTMLDocument hDoc = (HTMLDocumentClass)wB.Document;
  IHTMLElementCollection data = hDoc.body.children as IHTMLElementCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because the `Navigate()` method is asynchronous - in the second example you confirming the MessageBox is just enough time for it having completed, so it works - not reliably though.

Instead you should subscribe to the [`DocumentCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event and do your data collection in the callback.