# what's the best way to pause loop while webBrowser is loading page?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I need pause loop until that the webbrowser complete page load.

```
 string[] lines = (string[]) Invoke((ReadLine)delegate
                {
                    return logins.Lines;
                });


 foreach (string line in lines) {
    //..         
     if (TryParseUserDetails(line, false, out data) {
       //...                                      
          wb.Navigate(url.Next());
    }
}
```

how to wait the `wb` page load to before continue loop?

I tried using polling-flags, setting an variable as true in `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler` callback function.
and then:

```
wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(
                            delegate(object sender2,
                                WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs args)
                            {

                             done = true;
                         });
```

//..

```
  wb.Navigate(url.Next();
  while (!done)
   {

   }
   done = false;
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
wb.WaitForDone();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use an AutoResetEvent instead of the boolean. Like:

Outside the loop:

```
AutoResetEvent evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Then the event handler:

```
wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(
                        delegate(object sender2,
                            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs args)
                        {
                            evt.Set();
                        });
```

and then in the loop:

```
evt.WaitOne();
```

Comment: You might wanna replace that EventHandler with something like: `wb.DocumentCompleted += (o, args) => evt.Set();` - just to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do the stuff you want within the `DocumentCompleted` Callback like stated here: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212825/nullreferenceexception-with-system-windows-controls-webbrowser-wpf/8212925#8212925)?

Comment: I have a lot of links to acess in webBrowser,I need do it acessing link by link.

Comment: When you really need to to this Tudor's answer will best fit your needs.