# Visual basic loop without freezing program?

Tags: vb.net

I made a loop below to make a monster move around in my game, when the loops runs once the whole game freezes... any ideas to make the loop repeat every 5 seconds?

```
            Randomize()
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((4 * Rnd()) + 1))
    Do
        If value = 1 Then
            If Me.mob2.Location.X < 750 Then
                Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X + 1, Me.mob2.Location.Y)
            End If
        ElseIf value = 2 Then
            If Me.mob2.Location.Y < 549 Then
                Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X, Me.mob2.Location.Y + 1)
            End If
        ElseIf value = 3 Then
            If Me.mob2.Location.X > 12 Then
                Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X - 1, Me.mob2.Location.Y)
            End If
        ElseIf value = 4 Then
            If Me.mob2.Location.X < 750 Then
                Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X + 1, Me.mob2.Location.Y)
            End If
        End If
    Loop
```

Timer That doesn't work:

```
    Private Sub Timer()
    ' Timer.interval = 1000
End Sub
```

Comment: You can put a timer on that function to be called every 5 seconds, then you can remove the loop entirely.

Comment: The Problem is: what timer, I did Thread.Sleep(50) and it still froze... plus that freezes the while program, not the function...

Comment: You have to make a timer, it is an object in VB (you can drag it in from the UI editor or declare one yourself on load).  The timer will have a function that it will call every x milleseconds, so you just have the timer's tick call your function, then remove the loop all together.

Comment: As you have it now you just have an infinite loop, so it will just keep going forever locking your program.  Adding a sleep doesn't change the fact that it is an infinite loop and will never complete thus locking your program.

Comment: oh, I was trying to make it like a AI for my monster to walk around, any ideas how to do this without a infinite loop?

Comment: Timer dosn't seem to work... Heres the code I tryed: `code`     Private Sub Timer()
        ' Timer.interval = 1000
    End Sub `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not a good solution but this will help you to understand the problem

the problem in that your screen is not refreshing try this:

```
    Do

    application.doevents() '' so each time it loops it will refresh your screen

    If value = 1 Then
        If Me.mob2.Location.X < 750 Then
            Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X + 1, Me.mob2.Location.Y)
        End If
    ElseIf value = 2 Then
        If Me.mob2.Location.Y < 549 Then
            Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X, Me.mob2.Location.Y + 1)
        End If
    ElseIf value = 3 Then
        If Me.mob2.Location.X > 12 Then
            Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X - 1, Me.mob2.Location.Y)
        End If
    ElseIf value = 4 Then
        If Me.mob2.Location.X < 750 Then
            Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X + 1, Me.mob2.Location.Y)
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: See [Use of Application.DoEvents()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents/5183623#5183623) and [How to use DoEvents() without being “evil”?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11352575/719186)  DoEvents is probably the wrong suggestion here.

Comment: I agree, but making a graphic object just with vb no extra libraries is the first mistake

Comment: Thanks :D that was very helpful, I would Vote the it as useful, but I don't have 15 rep points :P

Comment: Is visual basic bad? what language do you suggest for games? @bto.rdz

Comment: vb is perfect, but this is not the best solution since your app will be slow, because each time you call doevents it refreshes all your app, check the articles that @LarsTech mention, you can just check my answer as solution click in the check below up and down votes, it will give you some reputation