# Pause image with c#

Tags: c#, image, timer, slideshow

I want to make a program that shows an image every 5 seconds , then pause for 1 second and then show the next .But i have a problem pausing the image.If i have the message box code , it stops shows the image and i have to press ok to continue , but if not no image is shown and it jumps to the last image. help please , what i have to add in my code to work properly?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr1 =
        new string[] { "water", "eat", "bath", "tv", "park", "sleep" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        button1.BackgroundImage = 
            (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(arr1[i]);
        new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.nero).Play();
        MessageBox.Show(arr1[i].ToString());

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty confused what purpose the message box serves here, but further, `Thread.Sleep` isn't going to be the right solution.

Comment: The message box is maybe just a debug solution to see whether the loop runs at all. Of course, after closing the box, the UI is refreshed, which is not the case without the message box.

Comment: message box isnt something i need , its just for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the UI thread has no chance to update the display. That is: The images *are* being shown, but the UI does not update.

A not-so-nice-hack would be to use `Application.DoEvents` to let the UI update itself like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    button1.BackgroundImage = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(arr1[i]);
    Application.DoEvents();

    new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.nero).Play();

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Another (much cleaner) solution would be to change your logic so that when pressing the button a timer is started that changes the pictures, running every 5 seconds. I'm assuming you're using Windows Forms, so you can place a `Timer` named `timer` on your form, attach an event handler to the `Elapsed` event and then use this:

```
// These are instance members outside any methods!!
private int currentImageIndex = 0;
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "water", "eat", "bath", "tv", "park", "sleep" };

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // EDIT: As per comments changed to turn the button into a Start/Stop button.
    //       When the button is pressed and the timer is stopped, the timer is started,
    //       otherwise it is started.

    // Stop the timer if it runs already
    if (timer.Enabled)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

    // Start the timer if it was stopped
    else
    {
        // Make the timer start right away
        currentImageIndex = 0;
        timer.Interval = 1;

        // Start the timer
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Within the timer event, use this code:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    timer.Stop();
    try
    {
        timer.Interval = 5000; // Next time, wait 5 secs

        // Set the image and select next picture
        button1.BackgroundImage = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(arr1[currentImageIndex]);
        currentImageIndex++;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Only start the timer if we have more images to show!
        if (currentImageIndex < arr1.Length)   
            timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This can work, and it's probably okay here, but DoEvents() can have some dangerous side effects.

Comment: What would be the right code to use a timer when pressing the button ?

Comment: @marios Was editing the answer while you wrote the comment. Please see code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I read that `DoEvents` is not recommended, but I never actually understood why - do you have a quick read on the negative effects or do I need to google? :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352301/how-to-use-doevents-without-being-evil/11352575#11352575

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn is there a way in the same button then is pressed again (while is running the program) to freeze it on the image that was pressed and then when i press it again starts from the start?

Comment: @marios Do you mean for the timer solution or for the `DoEvents` solution? I'll edit my answer to show you that for the timer solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is in conjunction with a Timer Control. Set the interval for your timer to 1 second, but leave it disabled initially. Then the button press code simply enables the timer.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private int ImagePosition = 0;
    private string[] arr1 = new string[] { "water", "eat", "bath", "tv", "park", "sleep" };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImagePosition = 0;
        RotateImage();
        Timer1.Start();      
    }

    private void RotateImage()
    {
        button1.BackgroundImage = 
        (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(arr1[ImagePosition]);
        new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.nero).Play();
        ImagePosition++;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImagePosition > 5)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        RotateImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Negative side effect of this code: The timer will wait for one second before the first image is shown. Also I'd really like to note that based on syntax conventions, variable names start with small letters in C# :-)

Comment: Fixed the delay issue

Comment: :-D Nice solution to the problem.