# WinForm, Dynamic Label delete (Beginner)

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, label

I made 10 Labels dynamically.

Now, I'd like to delete them with the same way (dynamically).

What do I have to do ?

Thanks..

```
for( int i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++ )
{
    var myLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    myLabel.Text = "dynaLabel_" + i.ToString();
    myLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, i * 23);       
    Controls.Add(myLabel);
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(199);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you **tried** removing them from `Controls`?

Comment: @AlexGravely Thanks commet. What do you mean by "Controls"?

Comment: You may find it easier if you name your controls such as "dynalabel_"+i.tostring(), as you can then look through by name and not accidentally delete a label you wish to keep

Comment: A word of advice, don't use `DoEvents()` unless you _fully_ understand the ramifications:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352301/how-to-use-doevents-without-being-evil

Comment: @DonBoitnott Nah.. If I "//" the DoEvents, nothing is going to change. Even, there is no Label at all.

Comment: Becaus, I guess, my codes goes like this.   private void button1_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
   Make_it();
  }

Comment: @Jason do events forces the application to process all outstanding events immediately, most of the time its harmless, however in some instances its can cause major problems `Refresh()` before the sleep should safely do the same

Comment: I'll try it out. Thanks for high level tips.

Comment: @Jason note the reason that nothing is happening with out the DoEvents() is that winforms is by default single threaded, this means that your sleep command is suspending the graphics on the form as well as the loop

Comment: Yes, you are hundread times right. I have pain in the neck because of that. Anyways, "Refresh()" works fine with me. Thanks.

Comment: a simple way of making it multithreading and not having that problem is to use a backgroundworker see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Comment: @MikeT Homeworks ? ^^  Thanks, I'll check it out with leisure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is this your homework?

```
using System.Linq;
...
foreach(Control c in Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList())
{
    //check if correct label if you need to
    Controls.Remove(c);

}
```

Comment: LoL.. Kind of.. for late 40's student.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Brief error:  Error CS1061 
'Control.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and 
no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'Control.ControlCollection' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: do you have a `using System.Linq;` at the top of the page?

Comment: Hmm. Just added "using System.Linq;"

Comment: Unfortunately, this leads to *resource leakage*: you should `Dispose` removed labels

Comment: System.Linq exands all enumerable lists with many useful functions, its usually included by default

Comment: I added "Linq", but still have the same error message.

Comment: @MikeT: `Controls.OfType<Control>()` and only then `.ToList()`, the loop should be `foreach(Control c in Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList())`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you, been a while since i worked in winforms i'd forgotted controls collection only implements IEnumerable not IEnumerable<Controls>

Comment: I have to clikc 4 times.
Once, odd numbered Labels gone.(I have 2, 4, 6, 8 and 10)
Twice, half gone (I still have 4, 8)
Third, # 8 gone.
Last, OK, have nothing.
Looks not good.

Comment: please note that in order to keep this simple i've missed out the final clean up operation, as a label contains links to the operating system then it wont always be deleted automatically because the operating system may still have a link to it, adding `c.Dispose()` removes the OS links

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple *for* loop in which you should *find out* label, remove it from `Controls` and *release* allocated resources:

```
// let's use regular expression to validate name; 
// String.StartsWith is also a good choice
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

// while removing, loop backward
for (int i = Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  Label label = Controls[i] as Label;

  // Control is Label with specific name
  if ((label != null) && Regex.IsMatch(label.Text, "^dynaLabel_[0-9]+$")) {
    Controls.RemoveAt(i);

    // do not forget to release resources allocated (here is HWND - window handle)
    label.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just saw it. It looks very nice. !!

Comment: Works beautifully. I, specially, like "RegEx" part. Big Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Controls` and `LINQ` `Where` to do the job:

```
var labels = Controls.Cast<Control>()
    .Where(c => c is Label && c.Text.StartsWith("dynaLabel_"));
foreach (var label in labels){
    Controls.Remove(label);
    label.Dispose();
}
```

Since you create the labels as `Label` and having the `Text` starting with value of `dynaLabel_`, your `LINQ` should also find those specific labels. Thus, you use both `c is Label` and `StartsWith("dynaLabel_")` there.

Comment: Unfortunately, this leads to *resource leakage*: you should `Dispose` removed labels

Comment: Thanks, `Dispose` is added.

Comment: Thanks. I just saw it. I'll try it too !!

Comment: @Jason ok, try it out. :)

Comment: calling `cast` and `is label` is redundant just use OfType<T>() to filter and convert should also reduce boxing wastage

Comment: Have to click "4" times.

Comment: I added "ToList()" blindly.