# vba: run a commund button while another one is running

Tags: vba, userform

I have two Command Buttons like these:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
CommandButton1.BackColor = vbRed
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"))
CommandButton1.BackColor = vbYellow
End Sub
'______________________________________________
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
CommandButton2.BackColor = vbBlue
End Sub
```

I'd like to run CommandButton2 while CommandButton1 is running.

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So you want to change the BackColor of CommandButton2 when you click CommandButton1?

Comment: No, I want to click CommandButton2 while CommandButton1 is running.

Comment: But it looks like the only thing that clicking CommandButton2 does is change the BackColor.

Comment: yes, but this is a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CommandButton1.BackColor = vbRed
    For X=1 to 15
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        DoEvents
    Next X
    CommandButton1.BackColor = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Your app will be more responsive if you can wait, say, 100 milliseconds each time, rather than 1 second.

Comment: Worth mentioning that DoEvents should be used sparingly...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352301/how-to-use-doevents-without-being-evil