# Pause program flow until WebBrowser loads a page

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

Im having to load a couple of pages consecutively in WPF application(.NET v4.0) with `WebBrowser` control and the easiest way to pause was to use a while loop and check for `IsLoaded` property. I was wondering if there is something better. The following [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317179/suspend-thread-until-webbrowser-has-finished-loading) response suggests use of `AutoResetEvent` but it doesn't seem to work i.e., `LoadCompleted` event isn't triggered and the `AutoResetEvent` is never set. Is there something that I've missed

```
private Uri firstURI = new Uri("http://google.com", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
private Uri secondURI = new Uri("http://duckduckgo.com/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
AutoResetEvent logEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public MainWindow() 
{    
  InitializeComponent();
  webBrowser.Loaded += webBrowser_Loaded;
  webBrowser.LoadCompleted += webBrowser_LoadCompleted;
  webBrowser.Navigate(firstURI);
  while(webBrowser.IsLoaded()){}; //logEvent.WaitOne();
  webBrowser.Navigate(secondURI);
  while(webBrowser.IsLoaded()){}; //logEvent.WaitOne();
  // do something
 }  

 void webBrowser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   logEvent.Set();
 }
 void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
    logEvent.Set();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking the UI thread with `logEvent.WaitOne()`, therefore *LoadCompleted* event (which will be executed on UI thread context) can never be fired.

I would write an async extension method like

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Task NavigateAsync(this WebBrowser browser, Uri  uri)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        LoadCompletedEventHandler loadCompleted = null;

        loadCompleted = (s, e) =>
            {
                browser.LoadCompleted -= loadCompleted;
                tcs.SetResult(e.WebResponse);
            };

        browser.LoadCompleted += loadCompleted;
        browser.Navigate(uri);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
await webBrowser.NavigateAsync(firstURI);
await webBrowser.NavigateAsync(secondURI);
```